# subprocess.check_output shows the error output when ignoring the exception

Tags: python, subprocess

Let's assume the command `test` exits with non-zero exit code and shows `Error!`

Now, when I do:

```py
try:
    subprocess.check_output("test")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    pass
```

it outputs `Error!`

Is there's a way to prevent it from outputting the error?

Comment: try: `subprocess.check_output(["test"], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)`; see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: @IonutTicus - Thanks a lot, I was trying `DEVNULL` only which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output("test 2> /dev/null", shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    pass
```

where `2> /dev/null` will take the `stderr` and throw it away.

Comment: Thank you but it seems `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` is better especially for cross-platforms.

Comment: `shell=True` is not recommended due to [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations)